# Is this statement correct? How would I go about proving it?

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers

There is an optimization for checking if a number is prime via "brute-force". It states that, given a positive integer $x$, one simply needs to check that all integers less than or equal to $\sqrt{x}$ do not divide $x$ for $x$ to be prime.

I'm trying to communicate this fact with a statement and then prove the statement. This is what I have:

**Statement**:
Given a positive integer $x>1$, if all integers $2≤y≤\sqrt{x}$ do not divide $x$, then $x$ is a prime number. Otherwise, $x$ is a composite number.

I want to make sure that this is a short and clear way to communicate the idea. Furthermore, how would I go about proving this? I know that I need to show that checking all squares of integers starting from $2$ up to $x$ will "account for" everything, but I don't know where to go from there. I feel that the proof should be trivial and I don't think I have the mathematical arsenal for the proof.

Comment: If $n$ is composite then there are at least two primes $p,q$ (possibly the same) such that $pq$ divides $n$.  But, if both of those are $>\sqrt n$ then $pq>n$.

Comment: Should say:  you can run the same argument with $n=ab$ with $a,b$ not necessarily prime (you just need  to require $a,b>1$).  But it is sometimes useful to work with primes.

Comment: @lulu So, it is safe to say that all prime factors of a composite are less than $\sqrt{n}$, and a number with no prime factors $<\sqrt{n}$ is prime.

Comment: @SeanXie: The first part of that is not true -- the argument only concludes that _at least some_ of the prime factors will be $\le\sqrt n$. (Equality holds when $n$ is the square of a prime).

Comment: @Troposphere In that case, is my statement false? How would checking all integers $<=\sqrt{n}$ "account for" all cases if prime factors may exist $>\sqrt{n}$ (if this is a correct assumption)?

Comment: @SeanXie: If your $n$ is composite, at least some of the prime factors will be $\le \sqrt n$ -- so if you check that far without finding _any_, the number can't have been composite.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification :)